# error while inflating class IamgeView

Tags: java, android, android-inflate

my full Log Trace :

```
06-30 16:29:16.303 30023-30023/pb.myPackage E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
Process: pb.myPackage, PID: 30023 
and

roid.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #128: Error inflating class ImageView 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:714) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
at android

.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
at pb.myPackage.FeedFragment$3.onCreateViewHolderImpl(FeedFragment.java:689) 
at com.poliveira.parallaxrecyclerview.ParallaxRecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ParallaxRecyclerAdapter.java:132) 
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5482) 
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4707) 
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617) 
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994) 
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)


at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353) 
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574) 
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028) 
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2906) 
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3283) 
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 
at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:596) 
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055) 
at

 android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1695) 
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671) 
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525) 
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434) 
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055) 
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 
at 
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1091) 
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:801) 
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:815) 
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817) 
at android.view.Vi
ewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453) 
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388) 
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671) 
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525) 
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434) 
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453) 
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388) 
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) 
at android.widget.LinearLay 
06-30 16:29:16.893 30023-30070/pb.myPackage E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'java.beans.BeanInfo', referenced from method weborb.reader.AnonymousObject.setFieldsAsBean 
06-30 16:29:16.893 30023-30070/pb.myPackage W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 4167 (Ljava/beans/BeanInfo;) in Lweborb/reader/AnonymousObject; 
06-30 16:29:16.893 30023-30070/pb.myPackage D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x001f
```

well the error is pointing me to line 127 which is an imageView, my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="4dp"
android:paddingRight="4dp"
android:paddingBottom="2dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="2dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/upperEventView"
            android:background="@drawable/below_border">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="\@will.Smith"
                android:id="@+id/txtViewEventPublisher"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textColor="#ef414c"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/eventPublisherImageView"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/eventPublisherImageView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />


            <pb.myPackage.CustomImageViewCircularShape
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/eventPublisherImageView"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:src="@drawable/ryan" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="..."
                android:id="@+id/eventButton"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/eventPublisherImageView"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:background="#00ffffff"
                android:textColor="#ef414c" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title "
        android:id="@+id/textViewEventStory"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="#575757"
        android:editable="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/upperEventView"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />


        <TextView
    android:id="@+id/listIDTxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ObjectID "
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="0sp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtViewTimeStmp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:id="@+id/txtViewImgExistence"
    android:textSize="1dp"
    android:alpha="0" />


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/locationLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="#f5f5f5"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pager">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="7dp"
                android:layout_height="7dp"
                android:id="@+id/indicatorImg1"
                android:src="@drawable/indicator1"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:contentDescription="" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="7dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/indicatorImg2"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:src="@drawable/indicator2"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="7dp"
                android:layout_height="7dp"
                android:id="@+id/indicatorImg3"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                android:src="@drawable/indicator2"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />


        </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="4h"
                android:id="@+id/txtViewTimeStmp"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textColor="#919191"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="14-JUN-2016"
            android:id="@+id/textViewEventTime"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewEventStory"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewEventTimeIcon"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewEventTimeIcon"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewEventStory"
            android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textViewEventStory"
            android:id="@+id/locationLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Location"
            android:id="@+id/textViewEventLocation"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewEventLocationIcon" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewEventLocationIcon"
            android:src="@drawable/event_location" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewEventTimeIcon"
            android:src="@drawable/event_time"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewEventStory"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

java code , here am inflating my layout :

```
    @Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolderImpl(ViewGroup viewGroup, final ParallaxRecyclerAdapter<Information> adapter, int i) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    return new ViewHolder(getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_row, viewGroup, false));

}
```

and the most important thing is that this problem is not occurring on SDK 23, well i dont know about other SDk's but i only tested it on SDK 23 and 19 the SDK 19 is throwing this error. i checked some question similar to mine and i got to know that out of memory exception can be cause of this so i tried to not assign any image to my imageView but still the problem exists

no idea whats wrong here if anybody knows then please let me know

Comment: can you post your full xml please

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz please check the updated question

Comment: I just run your XML code and it is working fine for me, maybe the error is in your JAVA file "maybe" as the XML is working fine in my device

Comment: @remyboys did you tried to clean , rebuild your project ?

Comment: did you tried this on SDK 19 ? @RakshitNawani , yeah i already did the Clean , rebuild 
@ YasinKaçmaz